# Using microdot, the route decorator does not handle the client's request

Tags: routes, micropython

I've deployed [microdot](https://microdot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)  on a Raspberry Pi Pico W, with the purpose to run a webserver. The Pico is configured in AP_IF mode (as access point). Clients are able to connect the access point, although the webserver does not route the URL to the associated application - or at least it seems like that.

The code is quite simple:

```
import network
from microdot import Microdot
from microdot.wsgi import send_file

webserver = Microdot()

ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
ap.config(essid='NAME', password='PASSWORD')
ap.active(True)
    
while ap.active() == False:
    pass

webserver.run(debug=True, host=ap.ifconfig()[0], port=80)

@webserver.route('/')
async def index(request):
    return 'Hello, world!'

webserver.run()
```

Once the client is connected to the access point, accessing "http://192.168.4.1/" is unsuccessful:

[image]

It seems that the webserver fails resolving the given route, although I don't see the reason.

Same, unsuccessful result with even more specific routes.

**Below code shows the solution, where the route decorator is prior to run the server:**

```
import network
from microdot import Microdot
from microdot.wsgi import send_file

webserver = Microdot()

ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
ap.config(essid='NAME', password='PASSWORD')
ap.active(True)
    
while ap.active() == False:
    pass

@webserver.route('/')
async def index(request):
    return 'Hello, world!'

webserver.run(debug=True, host=ap.ifconfig()[0], port=80)
```

Comment: The problem has been solved; even if it is so obvious, I was not able to catch it: the "run" shall follow every server settings like "route" configuration... It sticks out like a sore thumb, but... So the topic can be closed.